# Regarding logical print working directory and physical print working directory

Tags: bash

I created a directory `del1` a directory inside tha tas del2 inside that as  del3 inside that as del4.I linked these directories as follows

```
midhun@midhun-Vostro-15-3568:~$ln -s /home/midhun/del1 zero
midhun@midhun-Vostro-15-3568:~$ln -s /home/midhun/del1/del2 one
midhun@midhun-Vostro-15-3568:~$ln -s /home/midhun/del1/del2/del3 two
midhun@midhun-Vostro-15-3568:~$ln -s /home/midhun/del1/del2/del3/del4   three
```

But when i try to print logical working directory of three and physical working directory of three i getting terminal output as

```
midhun@midhun-Vostro-15-3568:~$ pwd -P three
/home/midhun
midhun@midhun-Vostro-15-3568:~$ pwd -L three
/home/midhun
```

My doubt is shouldn't I get physical print working directory output as `/home/midhun` and logical working directory output as `/home/midhun/del1/del2/del3/` . I am confused about this .Please elaborate on this

Answer (score 0):

The `pwd` command will display the logical/physical pathname of the *current* working directory, not of a directory given on its command line (it should have given you some sort of diagnostic message about this).

To see the `-L` and `-P` flags in action, `cd` into the `three` directory (the link you created) and try `pwd -P` and `pwd -L`.

Comment: So you mean i should have tried something like this.. 
midhun@midhun-Vostro-15-3568:~$ cd -L three
midhun@midhun-Vostro-15-3568:~/three$ pwd -P
/home/midhun/del1/del2/del3/del4
midhun@midhun-Vostro-15-3568:~/three$ pwd -L
/home/midhun/three

Now it is crear thanks for  your fast response.

Comment: @SamuelThomson Not quite. The `pwd` command only takes the options `-L` or `-P`, but nothing else. It will give you the physical/logical working directory (the pathname of the directory that you are in). Don't give a pathname to `pwd` on the command line.